# How to reset to min date in HTML input type date

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting the minimum date in html5 date input, but I can still select a date prior to minimum date using date up/down arrow.

For example I have set the min date to `2018-02-22` but once I have selected the month or date using down arrow a date prior to min date is getting selected.

Can I restrict it using any HTML date property

**Setting min date and selecting it**

[image: Setting min date and selecting it]

**Able to select previous date & getting date in the console**

[image: Able to select previous date]

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var x = document.getElementById('date').value;
  console.log(x);
})
```

```html
<input type="date" min="2018-02-22" id="date">
<button type="button" id="button">Get Date</button>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?  Could be that browser doesn't correctly enforce min/max date.

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 64.0.3282.119 (32-bit)

Comment: Seems like every browser implements this differently. I checked on Edge browser, and I do not see any up/down arrows there.
So you can either hide the up/down arrows using CSS or explicitly use Javascript to prevent changing the date value below minimum.

Comment: @CapeAndCowl Yes every browser has their native handling for input type date

Comment: @CapeAndCowl you are right i checked in Mozilla and there I could not see arrows

Comment: Although the dates are disabled in the picker Chrome doesn't appear to stop you from using up/down arrows to go beyond the date range. But it does prevent the form from being submitted if the date is out of range.

Comment: Browsers don't really implement the min/max restrictions well on the textbox, if at all. If you want something that prevents the text from being changed to something invalid you should probably look at a date picker control library.

Answer (score 2):

For this (I can still select a date prior to minimum date using date up/down arrow)to happen you should set max date also,  as shown below

```
<input type="date" min="2018-02-22" id="date" max="2018-02-28">
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the browser only enforces min and max if you try to submit the value.

> If you use min and max to restrict the available dates (see Setting
>   maximum and minimum dates), supporting browsers will display an error
>   if you try to submit a date that is outside the set bounds. However,
>   you'll have to check the results to be sure the value is within these
>   dates, since they're only enforced if the date picker is fully
>   supported on the user's device.

But you can easily validate the value using JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var x = document.getElementById('date').value;
  console.log(x);
});
document.getElementById('date').addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (this.value < this.min) this.value = this.min;
});
```

```html
<input type="date" min="2018-02-22" id="date" required>
<button type="button" id="button">Get Date</button>
```